# SQL Server Multiple Table Multiple filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, multiple-columns

I am a new user in SQL and I can use some help with my code, please help!

I have two tables: table 1 ( Item Master ) and table 2 ( Purchase History)

- Table 1 has the items information like description, vendor, warehouse etc.
- Table 2 has every single transaction.

Table 1 example

```
ITEM        Warehouse   Vendor  
------------------------------
ITEM-0001   ATLANTA     AMAZON  
ITEM-0002   ATLANTA     AMAZON  
ITEM-0003   ATLANTA     GOOGLE  
ITEM-0004   ATLANTA     AMAZON
```

Table 2 example

```
ITEM        Purchase Date   Price       WAREHOUSE   RECEIVE DATE 
----------------------------------------------------------------
ITEM-0001   01/01/2017  $5      ATLANTA     03/05/2017
ITEM-0001   01/01/2017  $5.2        DENVER      02/03/2017 
ITEM-0001   01/02/2017  $5.4        L.A.        05/07/2017 
ITEM-0002   .... AND SO ON
```

I want to have a combined result set - like this:

```
ITEM(T1)    WAREHOUSE(T1)   VENDOR(T1)  Avg_Price(T2)   LEADTIME 
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
ITEM-0001   ATLANTA     AMAZON      5.33333     65 DAYS
ITEM-0002   ATLANTA     AMAZON  ... so on
```

Here's my SQL code:

```
SELECT 
    A.ITEM, A.WAREHOUSE, A.VENDOR, B.PRICE, B.LEADTIME
FROM 
    TABLE1 A, TABLE2 B
WHERE 
    A.ITEM = B.ITEM
    AND B.PRICE = (SELECT AVG(B.PRICE) 
                   FROM TABLE2 B 
                   WHERE A.ITEM = B.ITEM 
                   GROUP BY B.ITEM)
```

That part adds the average price without any problems. Now where I am struggling is when I want to add the LEADTIME. Any idea how to code that in?

LEADTIME is the average time that item arrives in for specific vendor and specific warehouse. For example item0001 arrived from vendor x to warehouse y in 6, 8, and 10 days then the leadtime will be the average of these days (8 days) for that vendor and that warehouse.

Please help!

Thanks in advance

EDITED : AFTER HELP HERE IS MY NEW CODE .. THANKS!

```
SELECT B.ITEM,
       A.VENDOR,
       B.WAREHOUSE,
       SUM(A.QUANTITY),
       AVG(A.PRICE) AS AVGERAGE_PURCHASE PRICE,
       AVG(A.RECEIVEDATE- A.PURCHASEDATE) AS LEADTIME,
    FROM ITEMTABLE B
    JOIN ITEMPURCHASETABLE A
    ON (B.ITEM=A.ITEM AND B.WAREHOUE=A.WAREHOUSE) 
    WHERE A.PURCHASEDATE > 1170101
    GROUP BY B.ITEM, B.WAREHOUSE, A.VENDOR
    HAVING (MIN(A.PRICE)/MAX(A.PRICE)) !<0.1 AND COUNT(A.PRICE) >3 
    ORDER BY INVENTORY_COST DESC
```

New question: date is the format 1YYMMDD is there a solution for this ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: You want to add lead time and you tell us this but you don't tell us what leadtime is.  What is lead time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Your code is not correct, you join to B but then have a where on the value from a sub-query.  An `=` here filters the values in B not sets a value.

As @marc_s suggests here is how to write this SQL without using 25 year old syntax.

```
SELECT  A.ITEM, A.WAREHOUSE, A.VENDOR, 
        AVG(B.PRICE) AS AVG_PRICE
        --, B.LEADTIME not sure this works don't know requirements.
FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM
GROUP BY A.ITEM, A.WAREHOUSE, A.VENDOR
```

You could also do this with a windowing function (see prior version if you care.)

Comment: thank you! I posted my new code, and it is functional. date is formatted 1yymmdd, is there a way to fix that ?

Answer (score 1):

Below is query to get similar result in Microsoft Sql Server.

```
SELECT A.ITEM
, A.WAREHOUSE
, A.VENDOR
, AVG(B.PRICE)
 , AVG(DATEDIFF(day,B.PurchaseDate,B.ReceiveDate)) AS LeadTime
FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN TABLE2 B
ON   A.ITEM = B.ITEM
GROUP BY A.ITEM, A.WAREHOUSE, A.VENDOR
```

Comment: `JOIN TABLE 2 B` is a typo.  Also why do you think the lead time is an average -- couldn't it be the last or first purchase date vs the receive date?  As I said, the OP has to specify it.

Comment: @Hogan, that is what, I understood from his requirement. His final solution also suggests the same.